# Pub Sub Cloud Job not running correctly on specified time

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a pub sub cloud function scheduled to run everyday at 12am GMT. The function fetches a user list from firestore, converts it to excel file and send this file to a receiver whose email is also fetched from the firestore via sendgrid api. The problem is when I schedule the job to run after a time duration (eg. after every 10 minutes or after 30 minutes) the job works fine and the receiver gets the email but when I schedule the job to execute after every 24hours i.e. at 12 am daily, then the receiver does not receive the email at 12 am gmt. The code for the function is :

```
const { initializeApp, cert } = require('firebase-admin/app');
const { getFirestore, doc, deleteDoc, delete:deleteDocument } = require('firebase-admin/firestore');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const serviceAccount = require('./serviceAcc.json');
const sgMail = require("@sendgrid/mail");
const excelJS = require('exceljs');

initializeApp({
  credential: cert(serviceAccount)
});

const db = getFirestore();

let receiver = "";
let newVisitors = [];
let todaysDate;

async function deleteCollection(db, collectionPath, batchSize) {
  const collectionRef = db.collection(collectionPath);
  const query = collectionRef.orderBy('__name__').limit(batchSize);

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    deleteQueryBatch(db, query, resolve).catch(reject);
  });
}

async function deleteQueryBatch(db, query, resolve) {
  const snapshot = await query.get();


  const batchSize = snapshot.size;
  if (batchSize === 0) {
    // When there are no documents left, we are done

    if (newVisitors.length !== 0)
    {
        let workbook = new excelJS.Workbook();
        const worksheet = workbook.addWorksheet('Sheet1');
        worksheet.columns = [
            { header: "Name", key: "name", width:"30"},
            { header: "Type", key: "type", width:"20"},
            { header: "EnteringTime", key: "enteringTime", width:"40"},
            { header: "LeavingTime", key: "leavingTime", width:"40"},
        ]

        newVisitors.map((value,id) => {

            worksheet.addRow({
                name: value.name,
                type: value.type, 
                enteringTime: value.enteringTime,
                leavingTime: value.leavingTime,
            });
        })

        workbook.xlsx.writeBuffer().then((buffer) => {

            const msg = {
                to: receiver,
                from: "venuemanager@acostadancecentre.com",
                subject: "VISITORS LIST FOR TODAY",
                text: `PFA visitor list for ${todaysDate}`,
                html: `<h1>PFA visitor list for ${todaysDate}</h1>`,
                attachments: [
                    {
                    content: buffer.toString('base64'),
                    filename: 'visitors.xlsx',
                    type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
                    disposition: 'attachment',
                    },
                ],
            };

            sgMail.send(msg)
            .then((response) => {
                console.log("Email sent successfully");
                newVisitors = [];
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(`Error while sending email: ${error.message}`)
                newVisitors = [];
            });


        })
        .catch((error) => console.log(`Error while making buffer of excel: ${error.message}`))

    }


    resolve();
    return;
  }

  

  // Delete documents in a batch
  const batch = db.batch();
  snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {

    const abc = doc.data();
    todaysDate = abc.enteringTime.toDate().toDateString();
    const enteringTime = abc.enteringTime.toDate().toDateString() + " at " + abc.enteringTime.toDate(). toLocaleTimeString();


    let leavingTime;

    if (abc.isLeft) {
        leavingTime = abc.leavingTime.toDate().toDateString() + " at " + abc.leavingTime.toDate().toLocaleTimeString();
    } else {
        leavingTime = "NIL"; // or set it to a default value
    }

    const newVisitor = {
        name: abc.name,
        type: abc.type,
        enteringTime,
        // isLeft: abc.isLeft,
        leavingTime,
    };

    newVisitors.push(newVisitor);


    batch.delete(doc.ref);
  });
  await batch.commit();

  // Recurse on the next process tick, to avoid
  // exploding the stack.
  process.nextTick(() => {
    deleteQueryBatch(db, query, resolve);
  });
}

exports.emailTask = functions.pubsub.schedule("0 0 * * *").timeZone("Europe/London").onRun(async (context) => {

    sgMail.setApiKey('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'); // Replace with your SendGrid API key


    db.collection('RecipientEmail').get().then((snapshot) => {

        snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        receiver = doc.data();
        console.log(receiver);
        });


        deleteCollection(db, "visitors", 10).then((res) => console.log(`successs`))
        .catch((error) => console.log(`faillllll: ${error.message()}`));

    })
    .catch((error) => console.log(`Error while fetching receipientEmail: ${error.message}`));


});
```

In this code what I am doing is that first I get the recipient email from firestore and then I copy the visitors list into a new json object array and after copying I delete the documents in the visitors collection using batch. Then, the new json object array (newVisitors) is converted to an excel file and sent to the recipient email using sendgrid.

I looked at the cloud function's logs. It says that function executed with status ok but the receiver still does not gets the email. When I force run the function or when I schedule the function within a time duration like every 10 minutes, the receiver gets the email. Below is a picture of the recent logs:

[Logs of the cloud scheduler job](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VasQ7.png)

The region of the cloud function and firebase is uscentral-1 whereas the time zone is GMT (London/Europe)

Comment: Not sure if this is the reason, but I've found many times when we try to do things at or around midnight, we forget that timestamp only knows of 1 day, so when we roll to the next day, it thinks its the previous day, and so we have to increment the day by 1 first so it knows its actually a new day.  As in, if its 11pm and we add 1 hour, its not the next day, its the previous day without doing this.  Its probably more complicated when its a remote cloud host that might have its own time zone different than the one we are in as well.

Comment: You're not dealing with promises correctly.  Your function needs to return a promise that resolves only after all the async work is complete. Right now, it's returning immediately and not waiting on any async work.  Calling `then` does not cause your code to wait for a result - it just returns a new promise.  Not handling promises can cause all kinds of unexpected behavior.  See the documentation for more details: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions

Comment: @DougStevenson Thanks I have added the await to the deleteCollection function and removed the corresponding then catch block in emailTask which is the exported function, but even without await the function was running perfectly for time durations like 10 minutes etc but not works at midnight as I mentioned in the problem.